# Method 'ExecuteAsync' in type does not have an implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to create my own `IHttpActionResult` type to return some results from my control but before even my action on my controller gets executed the following exception is raised:

> Method 'ExecuteAsync' in type 'Kevsoft.TestResult' from assembly 'Kevsoft, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

StackTrace:

> Kevsoft.Controllers.TestController.d__5.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine) at Kevsoft.Controllers.TestController.Get(Int32 customerId, Int32 attachmentId, Guid fileId) at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] ) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_3.<GetExecutor>b__2(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()

Custom `IHttpActionResult`:

```
public class TestResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly Stream _content;
    private readonly string _contentType;
    private readonly string _fileName;

    public AttachmentResult(Stream content, string contentType, string fileName)
    {
        _content = content;
        _contentType = contentType;
        _fileName = fileName;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var byteArrayContent = new StreamContent(_content);
        byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(_contentType);

        byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse($@"attachment; filename=""{_fileName}""");

        return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = byteArrayContent,
        });
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be referencing `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.4` nuget package.

Comment: Are you sure you rebuilt it (check your compile time errors) and that the expected project/assembly is being executed?

Comment: cleaned, rebuilt and it's executing that I expect.

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having the same problem right now.

Comment: I think it was some conflicting dlls